# IIS - ignore/deny access to specific pages

Tags: iis, iis-express, iis-8

I have hosted an asp.net project in IIS and I want to restrict logins to some pages/folders.

I want to restrict all the users to not open some directory files using url.

They have to be able to only access the `localhost/mypage/home` and `localhost/mypage/login`. but if I try something like: `localhost/mypage/resources/importantNotes.json` everyone can open it! So I want somehow to redirect/deny access to it.

Also I want to not "totally" ignore that typical path because I need that resources folder later in my code.

What I have tried:
HTTP-Redirect, this works well, it redirects to specific page but I loose total access to the files I have on that specific path!

I have also tried with filteringRules but still the same result, I loose total acces to that specific resource folder!

What should I try or what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the approach to block accessing folder and its contents using the URL Rewrite module.

You could select your site, open the **URL Rewrite** module.

Click the **Add Rules** option, select **Request Blocking rule** template and click the **OK** button.

Set `*` as pattern.

[image]

Set `{REQUEST_URI}` as Condition input. Set `/test_folder/` as pattern. You could modify it and specify your own folder name here.

[image]

Set **Custom Response** as Action type. set **Status code** as **403**.

[image]

click the **Apply** button and **restart** the site.

**Output:**

[image]

To block files in the folder, you need to set the `pattern` as `/test_folder/*`.

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly for my first folder, example: test_folder. What if I want to restrict the files in the folder too? E.g: localhost/test_folder/text.json ? Because right now I can restrict the test_folder but if I want to access the files inside of it, I can still do that

Comment: You just need to set the `pattern` as `/test_folder/*`. It will also block file access. Please see my [test result](https://imgur.com/a/pdMwLOZ).

Comment: In my case it had to be like: `*/test_folder/*`, idk why but it works this way. Thank you very much for your time and efforts. Much appreciated.